# wondering which encryption this is

Tags: decryption

I have this huge string

```
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
```

I suspected it was base64, so i decoded it and got this:

```
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
```

what kind of encryptions / encodings are these?

Answer (score -1):

It could be Base64. By the look of the decoded text, it might even have been double encoded base64. Anyway, it is impossible to say, whether that is true and whether there is any additional encryption. At the end of the day, that is an important property of good ciphers. You can't tell real data from gibberish.